# GTK+: How can I add a Gtk.CheckButton to a Gtk.FileChooserDialog?

Tags: python, gtk

I want to present a folder chooser to users, and allow them to specify whether that folder should be processed recursively. I tried

```
    do_recursion = False

    def enable_recurse(widget, data=None):
        nonlocal do_recursion
        do_recursion = widget.get_active()

    choose_file_dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(use_header_bar=use_header_bar,
                                               title=_(da_title),  # _( invokes GLib.dgettext
                                               action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
    choose_file_dialog.add_button("_Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
    choose_file_dialog.add_button("_OK", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    check_box_1 = Gtk.CheckButton("_RECURSE")
    check_box_1.connect("toggled", enable_recurse)
    choose_file_dialog.add(check_box_1)
```

But that fails, and generates the warning:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: 14:03:31.139: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkCheckButton to a GtkFileChooserDialog, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkFileChooserDialog can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkBox
```

What is a correct way to do this?

Comment: I changed `choose_file_dialog.add(check_box_1)`  to `choose_file_dialog.set_extra_widget(check_box_1)` and that works, and avoids the warning, but  the checkbox appears on the bottom right corner. How might I move it to the right?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, an answer is to use `set_extra_widget` instead of `add`

```
        check_box_1 = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Recurse source directory")
        check_box_1.connect("toggled", enable_recurse)
        choose_file_dialog.set_extra_widget(check_box_1)
```

But I do not like the placement of the checkbox in the lower left corner, so I hope someone has a better answer.